# ls command with human readable file size kornshell

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I am trying to make a simple korn script to list file size in multiple directories I am using loop to change the directory but the command
 `ls -lrt`
Giving me all the file details which I need but it's displaying file size in non readable format. I want to have it in readable format like 100k or 2M.

I tried
`ls - lh`
And
`ls -l --block-size=M`
Both not working in korn
Please assist.

Comment: I don't believe `ls` is a built-in command so probably you have another version of `ls` on your machine which does not support these non-standard options. If those options work from another shell on the same machine, check the path used is the same for both

Comment: eg. `whence ls` / `type ls` / `which ls` and compare `echo "$PATH"` output from each shell

Comment: I am using IBM Aix

Comment: and does `ls -lh` work from a different shell on the same machine?

Comment: I have another maching using linix in that     ls -lh is working

Comment: if you don't have a version of `ls` on your AIX machine that supports those options then you can't use them on that AIX machine.